# Как отобразить UIView элемент поверх всех экранов в UITabBarController?

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

Нужно сделать наподобие стандартного плеера в iOS. В верхней части экрана отображается один и тот же интерфейс проигрывателя для всех элементов в TabBar

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете правильно организовать иерархию контроллеров. Например: UIViewController -> UITabBarController. Т.е. добавить view(UITabBarController'a) в нужную область view(UIViewController'a).

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
tabBarController = [welcomeStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"tabBarController"];
//Добавить:
[self addChildViewController:tabBarController];
tabBarController.view.frame = /*правильный frame*/;
[self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];
[tabBarController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
//Удалить:
[tabBarController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
[tabBarController.view removeFromSuperview];
[tabBarController removeFromParentViewController];
```

Можете сделать отдельное окно UIWindow.

Зависит от того, что вам будет удобнее для вашей цели.

Comment: Спасибо, в принципе, хороший вариант. Нужна возможность редактировать экраны для UITabBarController в storyboard. Чтобы видеть, как расположены элементы в TabBarController и то что буде вверху экрана. 

В данном случае можно сверстать все что нужно в storyboard. А программно создать  UITabBarController из storyboard и добавить в некий главный UIViewController. Поверх нужный элемент UIView. И frame для UITabBarController взять с вычетом UIView элемента.

Comment: @Dim Добавил инициализацию tabBarController'a. Сам tabBarController должен быть в storyboard и иметь правильный идентификатор.